# Creating the custom url aliases for nodes?

Tags: uri

I had a problem with making custom url aliases for drupal node pages.Basically my website have two articles types parent articles and child articles. Each parent article contains many child articles. So the each parent articles shows all  it's child articles in pagination.
current format
parent article : http://example.com/parent-title
child  article : http://example.com/parent-title?page=1, http://example.com/parent-title?page=2 go to each child artilces of parent article.

however I want to insert title of the child article as url alias so expected format is 
http://example.com/parent-title/child-title?page=1

How can i insert that child article title as url alias? I need this because this is very good for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Path Auto](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fpathauto&ei=2Fm2U-_nFIe9ugTy4ICoDw&usg=AFQjCNFWdYt4kFBkSxL6oiJikr-eaHAsuQ&bvm=bv.70138588,d.c2E) module for this purpose. It has many patterns options for each content type.

You can generate alises pattern for child articles and parent article separately.
I have added a screenshot that how it looks in the back end.

If it does not fulfill your requirement then we can customize the urls on saving with [hook_url_inbound_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) function in our custom module.

[image]